# Django annotating fields with null values

Tags: python, django, django-q, django-annotate

I have list of `Demand` objects that have `allocated` field that would either be `null` or have a name (denoting this demand's allocation).

I use annotations to count allocated/unallocated numbers per team:

```py
Demand.objects.filter(project=project).values('team').annotate(
            unallocated=Count('allocated', filter=Q(allocated__isnull=True)),
            allocated=Count('allocated', filter=Q(allocated__isnull=False))
        )
```

What's weird is that the numbers for the `allocated` annotation come out right, but the numbers for the `unallocated` are always zero.

For instance:

```py
list(Demand.objects.filter(project=project).values('allocated', 'team'))
```

With the following outcome:

```
[{'allocated': None, 'team': 'Design'},
{'allocated': None, 'team': 'Engineering'},
{'allocated': None, 'team': 'Engineering'},
{'allocated': None, 'team': 'Engineering'},
{'allocated': None, 'team': 'Delivery'},
{'allocated': None, 'team': 'Product'}]
```

but the annotations with have just this:

```
<QuerySet 
[{'team': 'Delivery', 'unallocated': 0, 'allocated': 0},
{'team': 'Design', 'unallocated': 0, 'allocated': 0},
{'team': 'Engineering', 'unallocated': 0, 'allocated': 0},
{'team': 'Product', 'unallocated': 0, 'allocated': 0}]>
```

Am I doing it wrong or it may be a bug?

Comment: That is because `Count(..)` does not count `NULL`. That is how SQL specifies that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because [**`Count(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count-1) does not count `NULL`, that is how SQL specifies how a `COUNT` aggregate works: it does not consider `NULL` values (this is also the case for `AVG` for example). But you can instead count the primary key for example:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Demand.objects.filter(project=project).values('team').annotate(
    unallocated=Count('pk', filter=Q(allocated=None)),
    allocated=Count('allocated', filter=Q(allocated__isnull=False))
).order_by('team')
```

Therefore, you can also simplify `allocated` to:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Demand.objects.filter(project=project).values('team').annotate(
    unallocated=Count('pk', filter=Q(allocated=None)),
    allocated=Count('allocated')
).order_by('team')
```